# update remaining time in childs of Expendable List View every second android

Tags: android

**the code views the remaining time every second but no action has been done ..i can't collapse group , expand another group or click on child ..Please i need help :( **

**in Profile Fragment**

```
expListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {    
     @Override
     public void onGroupExpand(final int groupPosition) {
        // notify=true;
        SharedPreferences prefs = rootview.getContext().getSharedPreferences("QuranerUser", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
        editor.putInt("center_pos", groupPosition);
        editor.putString("centerid", result.get(0).get(0).get(0).get(groupPosition));
        editor.commit();

        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) rootview.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        final TextView newtime=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rtime);

        LayoutInflater infalInflater2 = (LayoutInflater)  rootview.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater2.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);


        m_Runnable = new Runnable() {
            public void run() {                    
                for(int i=0;i<re_result.get(groupPosition).size();i++){                          
                      r_t=Long.parseLong(re_result.get(groupPosition).get(i));
                      r_t=r_t-1;
                      if(r_t>0){
                        re_result.get(groupPosition).set(i, Long.toString(r_t));
                        listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();                                 
                        ExpandableListAdapter.formate_Remainig(re_result.get(groupPosition).get(i)));
                        //  resetDataCell(v);

                        }
                        // update every second                    
                }

                m_Handler.postDelayed(m_Runnable, 1000);
            }}; 

         Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                 listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Expanded",
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
    });


 // Listview Group collasped listener
 expListView.setOnGroupCollapseListener(new OnGroupCollapseListener() {

     @Override
     public void onGroupCollapse(int groupPosition) {
         notify=false;
           Toast.makeText(getActivity(),
                 listDataHeader.get(groupPosition) + " Collapsed",
                 Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

     }
 });
```

**In ExpandableListAdapter:**

```
final TextView newtime=(TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.rtime);
final Thread testthread = new Thread() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);       
        try {
            while(true) {
                sleep(1000);
                MyProfileFragment.m_Handler.post(MyProfileFragment.m_Runnable);
            }
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
};

testthread.start();

newtime.setText(formate_Remainig(Rem.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition)));
time_schedule=Start_time(Long.parseLong(EN.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition)),Long.parseLong(ST.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition)),Integer.parseInt(offset.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition)));

String check = check_time(Long.parseLong(EN.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition)), Long.parseLong(ST.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition)),Days.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition));

if(check.equalsIgnoreCase("time")){
    newtime.setVisibility(TextView.VISIBLE);
    newtime.setText(formate_Remainig(Rem.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition)));}
```

Answer (score 0):

what about using **AsyncTask** ?

i made it in listview with progress bar in every row

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
download(view);}
}
);

void download{
  TextView tvTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
//use async task to update it
}
```

Comment: thanks for replay :))..i try this but i have the same problem .. the problem when i use "listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()" the adapter still refresh in Runnable and i can't do any event in expendablelistview..if you do this, can u support me with  example ..

Comment: you can use 
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {

Comment: Thanks amorenew ,i try this but still have the same problem ..how you notify textview in listview every second without using notifyDataChanged ??..notifyDataSetChanged redraws the entire view and caused a major performance hit for my application.

Comment: handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            progressTextHashMap.get(soraNo).setText(String.valueOf(progress));
                            progressTextHashMap.get(soraNo).invalidate();
                            ((ChooseSorasDownloadAdapter) lvSorasDownload.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
                            lvSorasDownload.invalidateViews();

Comment: Still have same problem with view after using invalidateViews

Comment: try myListView.getChildAt(position).invalidate

Comment: it worked only in listview not in expendablelistview